# Using for_each to print the highest value in a vector

Tags: c++, foreach

I've this code:

```
vector<pair<double, complex<double>>> vC;
GetFourierCoeffs(N, t, A, vC);
```

so vC is a vector that contains pairs with doubles and complex numbers
I need to use `for_each` to print the 6 complex numbers with higher norm, how can i do it?

I´ve tried creating a new vector, but I need to do it only with `for_each`

Comment: Why do you need to do use `std::for_each`? `std::reduce` or a basic `for` loop seem like way better choices to me

Comment: *"I need to do it only with for_each"* - Can you elaborate on why you have to use `for_each`?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how creating a new vector can help printing the current one.

Anyway - you can try the following code for printing the content of `vC`:

```
for (auto const & elem : vC)
{
    auto const & doubleValue = elem.first;
    auto const & complexValue = elem.second;
    // TODO: print doubleValue and complexValue in your print method of choice.
}
```

You can also use `std::for_each` to achieve a similar result:

```
std::for_each(vC.begin(), vC.end(), 
    [](pair<double, complex<double>> const & elem)
{
    auto const & doubleValue = elem.first;
    auto const & complexValue = elem.second;
    // TODO: print doubleValue and complexValue in your print method of choice.
});
```

Regarding getting specific values (6 with highest norm) - you can sort the vector with a custom comparator that uses the norm.